# Canada Elections Climate Change and God

Tags: canada, elections

I just saw this BBC news article.

[Canada election: Charities warned against climate change ads](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-49400492)

> Canada's election watchdog has warned environmentalists that saying climate change is real could break the law.
>
> The issue arose because one party running in October's election denies climate change is a threat.
>
> That has led Elections Canada to warn groups that running paid advertisements about climate change could be considered partisan activity.

So what happens if an atheist runs for office?

Are paid advertisements about God/Religion banned, during the election?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such an ad would constitute an issue ad, because it doesn't have a relationship to a party platform, which is the legal basis for the Elections Canada announcement. The "issue" issue could easily change. The law could also [change](https://www.fin.gc.ca/n18/18-101-eng.asp), and if the change is adopted it will be retroactive (probably not this election cycle, but it's also probably too late to invent a partisan issue regarding religion).